# Script errors in C# webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control, chatbot, twitch

I am developing a Twitch chat bot and I want to be able to display the current chat in the bot using a webbrowser control. I get "An error has occured in the script on this page. URL : https://web-cdn.ttvnw.net/sw.js"

I can get it to work with gecko or cefsharp web browsers, however; they are way too big. I want to keep my application under 10mb.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: What is this? Windows application or Web?

Comment: It is a WPF application

Comment: WPF webbrowser control is just to show properly running page, it can be from web or just index file. Does your page runs properly without using WPF. I mean through browser?

Comment: Yes through the browser it owrks fine. https://www.twitch.tv/edude15000/chat is the page. It just will not work through WPF webbrowser

Comment: I believe the WPF browser runs at IE 8 or 9.  You can change a registry key to get it to run up to IE 11.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/19bdbd98-83a3-4787-8d85-7f2d6f0446f9/featurebrowseremulation-code-for-ie11?forum=iewebdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

The Script file(s) (.js) on your website should be at bottom of the html file and then after (If you have access to it)
Add meta query to support in IE
The query is

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

I recently moved over to using WebView2 to solve this issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/

It uses the Edge browser as base and it works perfectly. The browser-code is very similar to the old WebBrowser as well.